# SQL netflix_data column showing different output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get info about the TVSHOW with the longest duration (in seasons)

```
select distinct duration
from netflix_data
where type = 'Tv Show'
```

This gives me all the available season duration that ranges from 1 to 17.

However

```
SELECT distinct duration, title
from netflix_data
where type = 'Tv Show' 
order by duration desc
```

When I try to receive the title along with the duration, the longest Duration ends at season 9, but there are clearly more. 
I really do not understand what am I doing wrong.

I am using SQL Server 2022.

This data is from Kaggle, netflix_data

Comment: This is probably just a quirk of the editor you are using for sql. Maybe it limits at showing  50 (or some number) of results and you have more than 50 combinations of title and duration.

Comment: The data is there, it's impossible that you'd have fewer combinations of title + duration than just duration. Just a display thing.

Comment: remove the distinct maybe there are duplicates

Comment: Or "duration" is actually stored as string/varchar. Because you are ordering by it descending the string "9" comes before the string "17".

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why are you using `distinct` anyway?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77623339/edit) your question to show the table schema you are using, especially how you have handled the `duration` column. In the `netflix_titles.csv` data set at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows) the original `duration` column is clearly freeform, including such values as `1 Season` and `90 min`, so it's unclear how you think SQL Server should handle interpretation and ordering of such data.

Comment: @Error_2646 You are right, the column is varchar. I have used ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(duration, 1,2) as int)  and it works.  I appreciate the help from everyone. Thank you!